# What determines the speed at which the aws-kinesis-agent processes and sends data to Kinesis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-agent

There is information on the Kinesis Firehose configuration in AWS - however not finding anything on the data process speed for the `aws-kinesis-agent`

Reference:

[AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html)

[GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-agent)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the configuration parameters in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html#:%7E:text=60%2C000%20(1%20minute)-,maxBufferSizeBytes,-The%20maximum%20size) there is a 4MB max limit on data size before it is sent to the delivery stream.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).